# How to deal with resolving random assembly and class names in Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, copy-protection

I use Json.NET for serialization and deserialization purposes, with TypeNameHandling set to `TypeNameHandling.All`. This writes the type and assembly to the json file, e.g. `"$type":"Testing.Utils.Entry, TestAssembly"`.

However, these names are changed when we protect the executable, which is changed everytime we protect it. So, I would like to make Json.NET automatically resolve the `Testing.Utils.Entry, TestAssembly` to what it is at runtime. This name could change entirely, also to '`ABC.DEF`' instead of '`ABC.DEF.GHI`' for example.

Because I want the entries to be saved consistently, the '`ABC.DEF`' type at runtime should always be stored to `Testing.Utils.Entry`.

Comment: Can't you export all serializable types to a different, non-protected assembly?

Comment: All separate assemblies are merged. I could do this, but then I have an additional library, which I don't want. I can't merge this one again as once the program is protected the assembly merger isn't working anymore.

Comment: Cant you set your code-protection to be deterministic? E.g. in .NET Reactor you can do this, so the names arent changed everytime to a new value -  they are transformed always the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future references, I managed to resolve this using a `SerializationBinder` with the `BindToName` and `BindToType` functions.

Comment: I'm struggling to make it work, and I have the same issue you used to have. Would you please post some code to help me out? I've tried every single posted solution with no avail. Maybe my lack of full knowledge on Object Oriented programming is the main issue.

Comment: Yes, use a format like this: new BindToNameSerialization { AssemblyTo = "YourAssemblyName", TypeTo = "TheNameOfTheClassYouWantToStore", TypeFrom = typeof(TheClassYouWantToStore) }. This can be used for both saving it and reading it. On the Json.NET website you can find the methods required for saving and reading where you can apply the SerializationBinder.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll give a try and let you know. I ended up posting a new question on the forum.